# Taking 2 keyboard inputs with sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

How do I make my "game" take 2 key inputs, for example if the user clicks w and d he moves up right.
btw, the variable `eventCheck` is an `Event` object

here's my current code(obviously not the full code just the event code):

```
while (window.isOpen()) {


Event eventCheck;
            while (window.pollEvent(eventCheck)) {
              switch (eventCheck.type) {
                case Event::Closed:
                     window.close();
                     break;
                case Event::KeyPressed:
                    switch (eventCheck.key.code) {
                        case Keyboard::W:
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
                            const Vector2f spritePos = sprite.getPosition();
                            sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x, spritePos.y - 5);}
                            break;
                        case Keyboard::A:
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
                            const Vector2f spritePos = sprite.getPosition();
                            sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x - 5, spritePos.y);}
                            break;
                        case Keyboard::S:
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S)) {
                            const Vector2f spritePos = sprite.getPosition();
                            sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x, spritePos.y + 5);}
                            break;
                        case Keyboard::D:
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
                            const Vector2f spritePos = sprite.getPosition();
                            sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x + 5, spritePos.y);}
                            break;
                                    }
                            }
                            break;
            }

            window.clear(Color(0,0,0,255));

            window.draw(sprite);
            window.display();
    }       
return 0;
```

Comment: `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed` is independent of events. You can call it in your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

1.) SFML has event polling through `sf::Event` and real time key state access provided through `sf::Keyboard`. If you only need to handle a single key press, your best bet is to poll them through `window.pollEvent` otherwise it's usually always better to get the state of a key and react based on the state. In this case you are mixing event polling with keyboard states. Choose one or the other.

2.) Not using sf:: removes a lot of clarity from the code

Now onto the code!

I wouldn't poll any user input inside events. I would get the state of the keys:

```
// Once per game loop
void ProcessInput()
{
    int keyCount = 0;
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        keyCount++;
        //Move Character Up, The more keys are pressed, the more i would mess around with speed/velocity here   
    }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        keyCount++;
        //Move Character Left, The more keys are pressed, the more i would mess around with speed/velocity here   
    }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    {

        keyCount++; 
        //Move Character Down, The more keys are pressed, the more i would mess around with speed/velocity here   
    }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        keyCount++;    
        //Move Character Right, The more keys are pressed, the more i would mess around with speed/velocity here   
    }
}
```

Depending on the amount of keys the user pressed, you would want to move your character less since they could move more diagonally than vertically/horizontally, but mess around with speed and velocity as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing

```
    bool moveL = false;
    bool moveU = false;
    bool moveD = false;
    bool moveR = false;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event eventCheck;
        while (window.pollEvent(eventCheck)) {
            switch (eventCheck.type) {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case Event::KeyReleased:
                switch (eventCheck.key.code) {
                case Keyboard::A:
                    moveL = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::W:
                    moveU = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::S:
                    moveD = false;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::D:
                    moveR = false;
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (eventCheck.key.code) {
                case Keyboard::A:
                    moveL = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::W:
                    moveU = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::S:
                    moveD = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::D:
                    moveR = true;
                    break;
                case Keyboard::Space:
                    jump(sprite, window);
                    break;
                }

                const Vector2f spritePos = sprite.getPosition();

                if (moveD && moveR) {

                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x + 5, spritePos.y + 5);
                }
                else if (moveL && moveU) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x - 5, spritePos.y - 5);

                }
                else if (moveU && moveD) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x, spritePos.y);
                }
                else if (moveU && moveR) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x + 5, spritePos.y - 5);
                }
                else if (moveD && moveL) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x - 5, spritePos.y + 5);
                }
                else if (moveL) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x - 5, spritePos.y);
                }
                else if (moveR) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x + 5, spritePos.y);
                }
                else if (moveU) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x, spritePos.y - 5);
                }
                else if (moveD) {
                    sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x, spritePos.y + 5);
                }



                break;
            }
        }

        window.clear(Color(0,0,0,255));

        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```